# How to reference to a previous bot message? (Discord.js v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to change a specific message's embed after a while, but I am stuck at fetching the reference to this message correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I first tried this:

```
const msgRef = await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed_1] });
let todos = []
todos.push(msgRef)
```

But when I try to use the msgRef object to update the message with another embed:

```
const message = todos[0]
await message.edit({ embeds: [exampleEmbed_2] });
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: message.edit is not a function
```

I am bit confused at this point. How can I properly fetch a specific message's reference to change the content later? Is there a way maybe to search for it via a message ID?

Comment: Looks like you're using interactions instead of messages, so remember that when you reply to an interaction, it doesn't return the "message" that you would expect, it's an [`InteractionResponse`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/InteractionResponse). To edit an interaction response you need to use the `editReply()` function again instead of just `edit`. Try using the exact same code but replace `message.edit` with `message.editReply`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch it via message ID but you would also need the ID of the channel it was sent in, then you can use the `Client.channels.fetch('channel id').messages.fetch('message id')` method which will return the Message object if it exists.